# Wordpress Ecommerce Lightbox Description

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, lightbox

I'm using the WP-Ecommerce plugin on a website.

Simple question, I need the description of the product to show beneath the lightbox when you click to enlarge an image.

Any ideas how I might go about doing this?

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a title="Your Description Text Here" to the lightbox hyperlink?

Comment: That worked for me. But I want to use the wpsc_the_product_description() and I had to apply strip_tags to it. Is there a way i can keep the html? I tried by urlencode but then it doen't render the HTML... any idea?